# ASP Net Core 3.0 Web forms. Working with Identity, is it possible to add a delete function to delete users?

Tags: asp.net-core, razor, project, identity

I recently started to study ASP Net Core. I started with web forms Razor pages. To get to the point, i have made a table which is connected to the Identity database. It contains the username and the email from the AspNetUsers table from inside the database. All good untill now. I'm trying to add a delete function to the table so i can delete the registred users with the delete function. I tried something but i don't know where i'm going wrong. If anyone can help me i will be very glad as i'm strugling with this for a while now. I will paste the code and maybe someone can give me a heads up. I'm trying to use the delete function as a OnPost which will be connected to the table with a asp-page-handler. Can anyone tell me where I am going wrong?

**.cshtml**

```
  @page
@model ProiectLicenta.Pages.Userlist.IndexModel
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "UserList";
}

<h1>UserList</h1>

<table class="table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>
                UserName
            </th>
            <th>
                Email
            </th>
            <th></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @for (var i = 0; i < Model.UserList.Count; i++)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>
                    @Model.UserList[i].UserName
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Model.UserList[i].Email
                </td>
                <td>
                    <a asp-action="Edit" asp-route-id="@Model.UserList[i].Id">Edit</a> |
                    <a asp-action="Details" asp-route-id="@Model.UserList[i].Id">Details</a> |
                    <a asp-page-handler="Del" asp-route-id="@Model.UserList[i].Id">Delete</a>
                </td>
            </tr>
        }
    </tbody>
</table>
```

**.cshtml.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

namespace ProiectLicenta.Pages.Userlist
{

    public class IndexModel : PageModel
    {
        private readonly UserManager<IdentityUser> _userManager;

        public IndexModel(UserManager<IdentityUser> userManager)
        {
            _userManager = userManager;
        }
        public List<IdentityUser> UserList { get; set; }
        public void OnGet()
        {
            UserList = _userManager.Users.ToList();
        }
        public async Task<ActionResult> OnPostDel(string id)
        {
            UserList = _userManager.Users.ToList();
            var User = await _userManager.FindByIdAsync(id);
            if (User != null)
            {
                IdentityResult result = await _userManager.DeleteAsync(User);
            }
            return RedirectToPage("Index");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`<a>` tag click event will send a Get request , so use `OnGetDel` instead of `OnPostDel` :

```
public async Task<ActionResult> OnGetDel(string id)
{

    var User = await _userManager.FindByIdAsync(id);
    if (User != null)
    {
        IdentityResult result = await _userManager.DeleteAsync(User);
    }
    return RedirectToPage("Index");
}
```